# Why does Calendar.getDisplayName always return the same day of week when given milliseconds?

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar

I'm trying to create an extension method to determine the name of the day within a week, given a specific Long value, so that it returns Monday, Tuesday, etc.

```
fun Long.convertFromLongToDayOfWeek(): String {

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    calendar.timeInMillis = this

    return calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault()) ?: ""
}
```

however, regardless of the value I pass to the calendar instance, it always returns "Monday".

I've written a few unit tests with Long values (which I receive from an API) and they all return Monday. Values to test with include the following:

- 1601542800
- 1601715600
- 1601629200

This code is complete and inclusive up to here, the following unit tests are just there to simplify debugging:

---

```
   @Test
    fun testExample1() {

    val value: Long = 1601542800

    val result = value.convertFromLongToDayOfWeek()

    Assert.assertEquals("Monday", result)

    }

    @Test
    fun testExample2() {

    val value: Long = 1601715600

    val result = value.convertFromLongToDayOfWeek()

    Assert.assertEquals("Monday", result)

   }
```

both of these tests are passing, but neither of these Long values represent Monday, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That is really strange and shouldn't be the case. Just in case, do you have some crazy mocking tools like PowerMock that allow you to mock static functions?

Comment: @EugenMartynov the tests are just there as a way of developing faster, when i run this on my phone it recreates this issue as well, that's where it started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all Mondays! They're actually all the same Monday, there's 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day, and those values are only a few hundred seconds apart

If you're getting timestamps in seconds from an API, you need to multiply them by 1000 to get millis (which is what the Calendar setter takes)

Comment: i'm also using epochconverter.com to verify these values, please also note that these are dates i receive from an api and they should be dates from different days

Comment: That site's assuming the timestamp is in seconds

Comment: If you're getting timestamps in seconds from an API, you need to multiply them by 1000 to get millis (which is what the ``Calendar`` setter takes)

Comment: cool, i assume the simplest answer is the correct one, let me test it and get back to you, thanks, probably a silly question

Comment: Nah it's not, our brains aren't used to handling such big numbers so it can be hard to tell if it looks right or not. We've all done it!

Comment: I never enjoy working with dates, regardless, thank you, accepted answer